# Pip not working behind firewall

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I am trying to use pip from behind a corporate firewall, and not having any luck.

I have set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables. wget works, but not pip.

I tried this ...

```
sudo -E pip install virtualenv
```

with these proxies ...

```
export http_proxy=myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080
export https_proxy=myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080
```

... and got a long stacktrace which ended with this

```
/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 214, in __init__
'Not supported proxy scheme %s' % self.proxy.scheme
AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme None
```

I looked at the poolmanager.py source. It looks like it is requiring the proxy variables to begin with a scheme. So I tried again with the following proxies ...

```
export http_proxy=http://myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080
export https_proxy=https://myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080 (also tried this with http://)
```

... and I get the following error

```
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement virtualenv
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for virtualenv
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

This is the same error I get when I do not have a proxy at all, though I get it much faster when the proxies are set.

When I try wget ...

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

It works fine, so I think the proxies themselves seem ok, unless I try them with pip.

Using the `--proxy` option instead of envvars did not help. Same results.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Bean

Comment: Try the -v flag to pip to get more output. Eg
`sudo -E pip -v install virtualenv`

Answer (score 24):

Use the --trusted-host argument.

I figured out how to get it to work with me behind my corporate firewall using the --trusted-host argument.

My first attempt was this:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

and the failed text was this:

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/: There
>   was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) -
>   skipping

So then I tried this which worked:

`pip3.5 install matplotlib --trusted-host pypi.python.org`

Answer (score 9):

I had to set all this in Windows to make it work.

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.corp.com:8083
set https_proxy=http://proxy.corp.com:8083
set all_proxy=http://proxy.corp.com:8083
set no_proxy=localhost,.corp.com

set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.corp.com:8083
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.corp.com:8083
set ALL_PROXY=http://proxy.corp.com:8083
set NO_PROXY=localhost,.corp.com

set PATH=c:\python27\scripts;c:\python27\;%PATH%
```

Please replace *proxy.corp.com:8083* with your http proxy server.

After that I use *pip install numpy*

[Last ".corp.com" was missing a period (fixed it).... by the way, after MUCH hair-pulling from behind our corporate firewall, THIS solution was the only one that worked!]

Comment: Thank you for answering Damian. Unfortunately I'm not at that job any more, so I can't even test if the above works on their firewall!

However I've upvoted your answer, as it's the most thorough and mentions variables that I did not know about, and might help others.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me as well... but something I didn't find anyware regarding when the password has special characters try setting as: `http://user:"password#with@special$chars"@IPADDRESS:PORT`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me (on linux centOS)

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://myusr:mypswd@myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://myusr:mypswd@myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080
sudo -E pip3 install --proxy http://myusr:mypswd@myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080 virtualenv
```

Comment: It says export is not defined

Comment: Sorry this is not so clear from my answer, but this is on unix
export is not available on windows, there you have to use SET

Answer (score 5):

`pip` has an option to set the proxy, so the following should work for you:

```bsh
sudo -E pip install --proxy="myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080" virtualenv
```

Comment: Thanks ... unfortunately this did not work either. It gives the same results as setting the environment variables, including the 'no scheme' issue if I don't begin the proxy with http.

I'm going to edit the question to indicate I tried this.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding "http://" before the proxy hostname:

```
sudo -E pip install --proxy="http://myproxyname.mydomain.com:8080" virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working behind a proxy

sudo -E pip --proxy username:password@http://IP:port install

Answer (score 0):

On windows go to **"Internet Properties" ---> "Connection" ---> "LAN Settings"** and check the address (if it is a wpad.dat file, download it and look for "ProxyPort" and "ProxyServer").

Then try:

```
pip --proxy http://*user*:*password*@P*roxyServer*:*ProxyPort* install *module*
```