# Pip3 install throwing EnvironmentError

Tags: python, pip

I've just had to reinstall python on my Widnows machine and have run into an issue installing dependencies through `pip`.

Regardless of what package I try to install, when I run `pip3 install <package-name>` I get the following error (eg. installing numpy):

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/50/42/f8310b51b3b9deccff3fe2e2b4e627ac8010f435f622ad225cd3ca6936ce/numpy-1.15.3-cp37-none-win32.whl (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)))
```

PC Info: Windows 10, Python v3.7.1, Pip 18.1.

Only last week I was able to install packages. I've had a look around SO and have tried a number of suggestions on running with trusted hosts, etc. but no avail.

**Edit:** Forgot to mention I am working on a University PC, hence behind a firewall. Just tried to run pip using the Uni's proxy settings but threw same error. Using my Macbook on the wifi (private not Uni PC) throws the same error.

I am assuming this must have something to do with the firewall settings?

Comment: Did you try rebooting ;) I know that sounds like a joke but the error message does say `'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'`. Maybe a reboot will clear up any strange connections.

Comment: Yes, rebooted when I installed python and again when the error message started coming up.

Comment: Can you access https://files.pythonhosted.org/ ?

Comment: I really recommend at least install VirtualBox and run Linux system of your choice. It really doesn't hurt :) Everything will just become easier.

Comment: No - I get the typical chrome `This site can't be reached`. Just tried on my Macbook and get `SSL is required` in safari.

Comment: try use virtualenv.

Comment: @RedCricket edited information above.

Comment: You could be right with the firewall. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39680454/9059420)

Comment: Same error unfortunately

Comment: Did you adapt the address to 'files.pythonhosted.org'?

Comment: Yes - tried files.pythonhosted.org, pypi.org and pypi.python.org

Comment: Are you in the US?  Does anyone else at your school have the same problem?

Comment: I am in Australia. Tried to use pip on a colleagues PC before and got the same error. Almost certain it is the firewall settings now.

Comment: Yep either the admins aren't giving you the right info about the proxies or the schools firewall rules are a little to restrictive. Maybe the admin is a hard core Perl guy and hates Python ;)

Comment: This is really weird... this morning numpy wouldn't install. Just then it did, but matplotlib wouldn't install. Come back 10mins later, matplotlib installs but other packages won't...