# Cannot install Pygame python 3.9.2

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to install Pygame and this message shows up:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pygame/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame
```

I am using python 3.9.2

Comment: Okay, so did you *read* this message? Did you *try to make sense* out of it? In particular, where it says stuff like `ReadTimeoutError` and `connection broken`, and `Read timed out.`, does that suggest that maybe the problem has to do with your internet connection?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the network its that pygame doesnt support python3.9

Comment: Are you doing `pip install pygame` or `python3 -m pip install pygame` and do you also have python2 installed and what is your OS

Answer (score 1):

From the error log you provided:

> after **connection broken** by '**ReadTimeoutError**("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read **timed out**. (read **timeout**=15)")

I guess you probably tried to install `pygame` with the `pip` module through the Command Prompt.
However, pip needs to connect to [pypi.org](https://Pypi.org) in order to download the module's files.

So, your computer probably failed to download the library.
This issue can be caused either by a poor Internet connection, or by an issue on `pip`'s side.

#### How to solve this issue:

1. At the time of posting, **`pip` seems not to be working correctly with Python 3.9** so you can:

   - [upgrade `pip`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15221473#15223296)
   - downgrade Python to a working version.

**[EDIT]** As of 2023, this issue is now solved.

2. **If this doesn't help, try these fixes:**

   - Check your Internet connection and retry
   - Maybe you are using a proxy: [override](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30992717)
   - The timeout can be overridden by typing this in the Command Prompt: `pip --default-timeout=1000 install [PACKAGENAME]`
   - It could also be caused by a firewall, which you can [override](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21468550#39680454).

Hope that helps!

Comment: the problem isnt pip it is that pyagem cant run on 3.9

Comment: I don't know I just read the error where it says "ReadTimeoutError" and "connection broken" - Maybe there are 2 problems at the same time

Comment: Are you insane its not the internet its that thee is no stable version for `python3.9`

Comment: the timout is a result of  `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)` not a networking problem

Comment: Indeed - if pip can't fin any version, then it searches indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

The most important part of the error message is:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame
```

You get this because `pip` can't find a stable version of `pygame` that is compatible with `python3.9` from `PyPi`.The rest of the error message is a timout that happens  because `pip` tries indefinitely to find a match but always comes up empty.

**These are your options:**

1. Wait for support to be added for `Python3.9`
2. Install the unsupported development verion like so:

   ```
   pip install pygame==2.0..0.dev22
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   python -3.9 -m pip install pygame
   ```
3. You can roll back your version to `ptyhon3.8` or earlier.

Comment: You should [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221473/how-do-i-update-pip-itself-from-inside-my-virtual-environment/15223296#15223296) pip - It works fine for me on Python 3.8.2.

Comment: are you using windows

Comment: Furthermore the newest version of `pygame` is 2.0.1 - another proof of your old pip version.

Comment: Sorry 3.8 is supoted but not 3.9

Comment: Right I didn't see (*"I am using python 3.9.2"*)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to give precedence to IPv4 over IPv6.

If you are running on windows, open CMD with administrator permissions and apply the following command:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::ffff:0:0/96 46 4
```

If you are running on Ubuntu (You can easily convert the commands for any other linux distribution):

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
```